# Using generated on the server AccessToken to connect to GCP Text to Speech

Tags: google-cloud-platform, access-token, google-text-to-speech

I would like to be able to connect to GCP Text to Speech from a react.js front-end using an access token generated on the server. I adapted the code from the [linked reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60006736) to produce an access token. However, I was not able to find in the docs how to use that token to connect from the front-end to GCP.

For simplicity, I would like to begin with modifying [the linked working node.js example](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#create_audio_data) from the docs to use the hardcoded access token instead of the Default Credentials File to connect with the service.

Here is my attempt (compared to the [example](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#create_audio_data), only the construction of `client` is modified):

```js
'use strict';

function main() {
  // [START tts_quickstart]
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');

  // Import other required libraries
  const fs = require('fs');
  const util = require('util');
  // Creates a client
  const client = new textToSpeech({tk: 'ya29.c.Kp8BCQj<etc.>'}).TextToSpeechClient();
  async function quickStart() {
    // The text to synthesize
    const text = 'hello, world!';

    // Construct the request
    const request = {
      input: {text: text},
      // Select the language and SSML voice gender (optional)
      voice: {languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL'},
      // select the type of audio encoding
      audioConfig: {audioEncoding: 'MP3'},
    };

    // Performs the text-to-speech request
    const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
    // Write the binary audio content to a local file
    const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
    await writeFile('output.mp3', response.audioContent, 'binary');
    console.log('Audio content written to file: output.mp3');
  }
  quickStart();
  // [END tts_quickstart]
}

main(...process.argv.slice(2));
```

I get an error that `textToSpeech` is not a constructor. How can I fix this example to connect to GCP Text to Speech using the access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to authenticate via access token using the Text-To-Speech Nodejs Client Library. The [TextToSpeechClient](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/text-to-speech/latest/v1.TextToSpeechClient.html) in Node runtime only accepts credentials objects which can be found from service accounts.

Based from the [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60006736) you included in your question, it generates the access token and uses it in Android. It makes sense since there are no client libraries for Android as of now, so the OP is using the Text-To-Speech REST API to create an HTTP request. Using HTTP request requires the access token to authenticate, thus the solution of the SO example.

My suggestions are the following:

1. Adapt the solution similar to the [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60006736) which is sending request via HTTP so you can use access token for authentication.
2. Use a different programming language like Python (seems unlikely since you are using React). It is possible [in Python Client Library](https://googleapis.dev/python/texttospeech/latest/texttospeech_v1/text_to_speech.html#google.cloud.texttospeech_v1.services.text_to_speech.TextToSpeechClient) to use access token for authentication since it accepts [credentials object](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/reference/google.auth.credentials.html#google.auth.credentials.Credentials).

Also just to add you are passing parameters incorrectly on your client object. It should be `const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient(object);`

Comment: Does the Python client library use HTTP requests or some other mechanism under the hood? If it uses some other mechanism, then maybe I can use it from my react.js code?

Comment: P.S. Thank you for opening my mind to look for alternatives to javascript for front-end. http://transcrypt.org looks like very much worth giving it a try.

Comment: What I know is under the hood, the Python client library calls RPC of Text-To-Speech, but I'm not sure if it uses HTTP. You can see the source code of the Python client [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/texttospeech/latest/_modules/google/cloud/texttospeech_v1/services/text_to_speech/client.html#TextToSpeechClient). You can also check the the RPC reference https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.texttospeech.v1#google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.TextToSpeech

Comment: Are there downsides of using HTTP requests instead of calls to client library functions?

Comment: As per [client library docs](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained), Client Libraries are created so the user can easily write code on their preferred language. Compared to HTTP were you will be constructing requests manually, as well as parsing the responses.

Comment: Thank you! It's a shame their client libraries are incomplete...